# jQuery button click when page load, keeps looping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, click, infinite-loop

I Have a chrome extension, it click a button when the page is loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      document.querySelectorAll("input[type='submit']")[0].click(); 
});
```

This works, the only problem is that the button is also on the next page. So it keeps pressing the button and the page keeps reloading, so it's in a loop.

How do I fix this?

Comment: have id for button for which want to trigger click so that you can differentiate

Comment: It's not my site, no ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to refine your selector. Find an unique parent element for the page you're targeting and create a more specific selector.

Another solution would be to check the current page url or the referrer and see if it matches a certain pattern.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
did it like this: 
if ( document.location.href.indexOf('zoeksuggestie') > -1 ) {
        document.querySelectorAll("input[type='submit']")[0].click(); 
    }
    });